# adding code for a Django admin field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a tinymce textarea in my django admin and I need users to be able to upload images (via AJAX) that will be linked in this textarea.

That would be accomplished by adding an "Image Upload" button (it's already working) in the top of the "Content" textarea.

What's the recommended way of doing that?

I can think on 2 solutions:

1. extending `change_form` and replacing `{% for fieldset in adminform %}` for the actual fields... and when it's the `content` field, I add this value
2. dynamically adding this button with javascript (find out where the `content` field is and add a `<div>` before it)

A better solution, if possible, would be to override just this specific field in the admin templates. Is that possible? Or are there better solutions?

PS: this field is not part of the DB (it just uploads one or more images, saves it to the storage and returns a link that will be included on the tinymce).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could  use this 
[formfield_overrides from the djangodocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) 
if not, create a subclass of modelform and overide the form of admin with ModelAdmin.form.